# JQuery UI Dialog does not open for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:14px" id="btnAdd" onclick="modaladdedit('URLToMyController')"><i class="fa fa-plus"> Add New</i></button>
```

HEAD Tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" />            
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/ionicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin-lte/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin-lte/css/skins/skin-black-light.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">        
<link href="/Content/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/datatablefooteredit.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

After `</body>`:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="/admin-lte/js/adminlte.min.js"></script>
<script src="/admin-lte/js/demo.js"></script>
```

Scripts after `</body>`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.sidebar-menu').tree()
});

 var Popup, table;
 $(document).ready(function () {
// Some code here...
});

// Popup Modal Window
        function modaladdedit(url){            
            var formDiv= $('</div>');    
            $.get(url)
            .done(function(response){
                  formDiv.html(response);    
                  Popup= formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    position: 'center',
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Add/Edit Email Data',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 600,
                    close: function (){
                                Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                            }
                 });                    
            });
```

When I click on the button, the dialog window does not popup and I dont get any errors in the console.
I tried everything and nothing worked. I tried changing the order of the css and js file but nothing worked really.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I can see you never add `formDiv` to the DOM. Thus it is not displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this even create a `<div>`?

```
$('</div>')
```

I'm not sure if it self-corrects for you, but the `/` should be at the end:

```
$('<div/>')
```

Additionally, even when you create your `formDiv` you never append it to the DOM.  Probably the ideal place to do that would be in the AJAX callback.  Something like this:

```
formDiv.html(response);
$('body').append(formDiv);
```

You can append it anywhere you like really, I'm just using the `<body>` element as an example.

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! The problem was with the slash at the beginning of `</div>` the DOM append didn't make a difference